# Grasshopper in a tropical forest

Tags: combinatorics

There is a Grasshopper in a tropical forest. The grasshopper can jump only vertically and
horizontally, and the length of the jump is always equal to x centimeters. A Grassshopper has found herself at the center of some cell of the chess board of
the size p×q centimeters (each cell is 1×1 centimeters).
She can jump as
she wishes for an arbitrary number of times, she can even visit a cell more
than once. The only restriction is that she cannot jump out of the board.The Grasshopper can count the amount of cells that she can reach from the
starting position (x,y). Let's denote this amount by d(x,y). Your task is to
find the number of such starting positions (x,y), which have the
maximum possible value of d(x,y)

Input
   The integer array contains three integers p, q,x(1<=p,q,x<=10^6)
   p = lenght of board
   q = width of board
   x = lenght of Grasshopper jump

Examples
   input : 2 3 1000000
   output : 6

input : 3 3 2
   output : 4

Comment: Please: Use another letter for the jump size.

Comment: Is this my task, or is it yours?

Comment: This reads like a problem from a coding competition. Well, maybe by now the competition is over.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/739397/find-the-number-of-such-starting-position-x-y-whic --- http://brainly.in/question/8100 --- http://www.careercup.com/forumpost?id=5648416625393664

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  think first about the case jump size $1$ for $p,q$ fairly large (say $4$).  Clearly a center cell can reach four other cells.  What cells cannot reach four other cells?  Then, as in your first example, notice that if $x$ is greater than $p,q$ you can reach the same number of cells from any place on the board.  What happens in the transition region?

Added: start from the center of the board.  On the first move you can reach four cells, for a total of five.  On the second move you can reach eight more, for a total thirteen.  See if you can find a pattern.  This will continue until you can hit the edge of the board.  How many squares can get to the edge of the board?  The rest will all have an equal number of places they can get.  You might look up [taxicab geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).  Longer jumps don't change anything except to expand the pattern.

Comment: Could you please explain it little more because I am unable to understand too.

Comment: @RasmiRanjanNayak:  see if this helps